# shift id's of table alike (id = id + 1) where id is primary key

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to shift all the primary keys for table alike

```
UPDATE TODO SET id = id + 1
```

but I can't do it (  [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/bd109/2) from Ahmad Al-Mutawa answer ) descript why. primary key can't be changed like this.

Also I can't ALTER the table according that this is sqlite: http://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html

I'm thinking about some hardcoded recursive change for other columnts but without tsql and stored procedures it's hard for me to get how can I make it?

Comment: *Why* do you need to alter values that, as here, appear to be arbitrary identifiers? You should just treat them as opaque blobs that *happen* to look like numbers.

Comment: @Patrick B. sqlite is very new for me, I can't use tsql and stored procedures. I don't know even where to start.

Comment: My comment was not meant to be an offense. You would be surprised how many people ask their questions with possible solutions (which is a good thing to do) without having tested them in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you execute your `UPDATE` command, you will get duplicate IDs temporarily.

To avoid this, change the IDs in two steps.
First, pick a number that is larger than the largest ID, and add it to all IDs:

```
UPDATE TODO SET id = id + 1000000000
```

Then, subtract one less from all IDs:

```
UPDATE TODO SET id = id - (1000000000 - 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

[image: It did not work]

It is not possible to update SQLite primary key without first altering the table (by removing the PRIMARY key property).

Here is the [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/bd109/2)

Comment: I see, but that's not possible to alter table. http://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html

Comment: @Ash in that case, you will need to create a new temporary table and copy data into it, then delete the first one, rename the temp to the same name as the old one.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if Sqlite has the feature to disable primary key. If yes, you can disable it, update the table and put the primary key back on.